# How to draw back into the scene a removed shape with Konva?

Tags: vue.js, konvajs

I used remove() method to delete a rectangle from the scene, how can i draw it back?

The documentation said: *"remove a node from parent, but don't destroy. You can reuse the node later."*

[Link to documentation](https://konvajs.org/api/Konva.Rect.html#remove__anchor)

I couldn't find any clue
Thanks

Comment: Can you make a small demo of your code? Do you use `vue-konva`? If so, you should not delete a node manually, just remove it from the template or render function.

Comment: i use Quasar framework with Konva (no vue-konva or react)

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the responses, i actually found a simple workaround.

I use .hide() and .show() methods because i want to keep intact the object for later use and when i do not need it anymore i'll just .destroy() the shapes.

The downside is you need more memory to keep all, but with few shapes on the scene is negligible.

Comment: Good to know you found a solution that works for you. Did you try my suggestion - it should have been as good as your own as the two are functionally equivalent in your question context?

Answer (score 1):

Just keep a reference to the node via a variable. For example, in the code below I add a node to layer1, remove it, and add it to layer2.

```
var layer1 = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer1);
Var node = new Konva.WhateverShape({....});
layer1.add(node);
layer1.draw();
...
...
var layer2 = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer2);
node.remove();   // at this time the node exists but is not on the stage
layer2.add(node);
layer2.draw();  // now the node is visible again.
```